# Determinant of function of matrx

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have two `K`-by-`K` matrices, `A` and `B`, `B` is diagonal. I want to find roots of the equation :

```
det(Ax+B) = 0
```

In `MATLAB`. `x` is multiplied element by element with `A`. I know that `det(Ax+B)` is a K-order polynomial of `x`.

How can I find the coefficients of this polynomial? If I find these coefficients, I can find the roots of the above equation by `roots()` in MATLAB. If not, I should use `fzero`.

Best
M. R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me the roots would just be `eig(B,A)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Symbolic Toolbox. The following illustrates how to do it:

```
>> A = magic(4) %// example matrix

A =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

>> B = diag([4 2 6 5]) %// example matrix

B =

     4     0     0     0
     0     2     0     0
     0     0     6     0
     0     0     0     5

>> syms x
>> det(A*x+B)

ans =

- 11016*x^3 + 1342*x^2 + 2568*x + 240
```

Comment: The [`sym2poly`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym2poly.html) function will be helpful if one wants to then use `roots`. That or `simplify(solve(det(A*x+B)==0,x))` if you want to keep everything symbolic.

Comment: Note that this solution will only work well for small dimensions K. There is no symbolic solution for the roots of polynomials of order  greater than 5. Root finding of high order polynomials also tends to be unstable when done numerically.